# RecursionError in sorting algorithm when using Numpy array instead of list

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, recursion

Here is my situation: I create a numpy array of 100,000 elements, shuffle the array, and then do one of three things:

1) Sort the array with merge sort, shuffle the array again, and then try to sort with quick sort, in which I get a "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison"

2) Sort the array with quick sort, which works perfectly fine.

3) Immediately convert the array to a list and do step 1, which does NOT throw any errors.

Why do I get a recursion error ONLY after running quick sort after merge sort?

Why do I not get this error when using a list instead of Numpy array?

Thanks so much for any help.

Here is the full code:

```
import random
import numpy as np

def quick_sort(ARRAY):
    """Pure implementation of quick sort algorithm in Python
    :param collection: some mutable ordered collection with heterogeneous
    comparable items inside
    :return: the same collection ordered by ascending
    Examples:
    >>> quick_sort([0, 5, 3, 2, 2])
    [0, 2, 2, 3, 5]
    >>> quick_sort([])
    []
    >>> quick_sort([-2, -5, -45])
    [-45, -5, -2]
    """
    ARRAY_LENGTH = len(ARRAY)
    if( ARRAY_LENGTH <= 1):
        return ARRAY
    else:
        PIVOT = ARRAY[0]
        GREATER = [ element for element in ARRAY[1:] if element > PIVOT ]
        LESSER = [ element for element in ARRAY[1:] if element <= PIVOT ]
        return quick_sort(LESSER) + [PIVOT] + quick_sort(GREATER)

def merge_sort(collection):
    """Pure implementation of the merge sort algorithm in Python
    :param collection: some mutable ordered collection with heterogeneous
    comparable items inside
    :return: the same collection ordered by ascending
    Examples:
    >>> merge_sort([0, 5, 3, 2, 2])
    [0, 2, 2, 3, 5]
    >>> merge_sort([])
    []
    >>> merge_sort([-2, -5, -45])
    [-45, -5, -2]
    """
    length = len(collection)
    if length > 1:
        midpoint = length // 2
        left_half = merge_sort(collection[:midpoint])
        right_half = merge_sort(collection[midpoint:])
        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0
        left_length = len(left_half)
        right_length = len(right_half)
        while i < left_length and j < right_length:
            if left_half[i] < right_half[j]:
                collection[k] = left_half[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                collection[k] = right_half[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1

        while i < left_length:
            collection[k] = left_half[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < right_length:
            collection[k] = right_half[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

    return collection

def is_sorted(a):
    for n in range(len(a) - 1):
        if a[n] > a[n + 1]:
            return 'not sorted'
    return 'sorted'

# Initialize
list_len = 100000                           # Define list len
print("Set list len to %s" % list_len)
data = np.arange(0, list_len, 1)            # Create array of numbers
# Alternatively: data = list(np.arange(0, list_len, 1))  <-- This WILL NOT cause an error
print("Created array")

# Shuffle
print("Shuffling array")
random.shuffle(data)                        # Shuffle array
print("List: %s" % is_sorted(data))         # Verify that list is not sorted

# Sort (merge sort)
print("Sorting array with merge sort")
merge_sort(data)                            # Sort with merge sort      
print("List: %s" % is_sorted(data))         # Verify that list is sorted

# Shuffle
print("Shuffling array")
random.shuffle(data)                        # Reshuffle list
print("List: %s" % is_sorted(data))         # Verify that list is not sorted

# Sort (quick sort)
print("Sorting array with quick sort")
print(quick_sort(data))                     # Sort with quick sort
print("List: %s" % is_sorted(data))         # Verify that list is sorted
```

And the full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Untitled 3.py", line 99, in <module>
    print(quick_sort(data))                     # Sort with quick sort
  File "Untitled 3.py", line 24, in quick_sort
    return quick_sort(LESSER) + [PIVOT] + quick_sort(GREATER)
  File "Untitled 3.py", line 24, in quick_sort
    return quick_sort(LESSER) + [PIVOT] + quick_sort(GREATER)
  File "Untitled 3.py", line 24, in quick_sort
    return quick_sort(LESSER) + [PIVOT] + quick_sort(GREATER)
  [Previous line repeated 993 more times]
  File "Untitled 3.py", line 22, in quick_sort
    GREATER = [ element for element in ARRAY[1:] if element > PIVOT ]
  File "Untitled 3.py", line 22, in <listcomp>
    GREATER = [ element for element in ARRAY[1:] if element > PIVOT ]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

The error is clearly happening when quicksort tries to sort the list. NOTE: I know that using lists would be faster, and I know that I could raise the recursion limit. I know that this could be caused by passing quicksort an already sorted list, but my code proves that this is not what is happening. Also, as I said before, quicksort works fine all on its own, so this is not caused by an infinite recursion loop. I am asking this question out of curiosity to gain a better understanding of why it happens.

Comment: The previous question alluded to is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934080/why-do-numpy-arrays-cause-a-recursionerror-when-lists-do-not.  It isn't obvious that you've added enough information to override the previous hold.  Is there enough information to reproduce the situation?  If there is then I could start adding diagnostic prints and tests to better identify what is happening.

Comment: @hpaulj I posted this question because it answered all of the complaints left on my last one. I'm not sure what you're asking when you ask if there is enough information to reproduce the situation. I have posted all of the code which causes the error, and I assume that if you tried to run the code on your machine it would yield the same. What more should I add?

Comment: OK, a copy-n-paste does hit the limit.

Comment: Looks like you needed to test that the merged `data` matches the original `arange` data, not just that it is sorted.

Comment: Yes @hpaulj you're right. I wish I had thought to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies with `merge_sort`.

One important difference between numpy arrays and lists is that the former return a view when sliced while the latter return a copy.

Thus `collection`, `left_half` and `right_half` all reference the same data when working on an array whereas in the list case `left_half` and `right_half` will be slice copies.

You can fix this by forcing a copy or writing to a newly allocated output.

As a result of this bug in the end some elements will have been overwritten while others occur multiple times. In fact there were lots of zeros when I ran a test.

This triggers worst-case behavior in `quick_sort`: Of a block of equal elements the recursion will shave off one at a time which is what makes it hit the recursion limit.

I don't know what the text book fix for that is but you could collect equal elements in a third group.

Comment: So this is a combination of the problems we suggested in the previous question - array's use of `view`, and `quick-sort` worst case.  Only the `view` error was in `merge-sort`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. That makes so much sense.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah looks like it.